# Assign template joomla with sessions

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I need to change the template depends on the sessions, that means Once user logged in we need to change the template.

note: I need to achieve this by coding not from administrator.

any help?

Comment: Why you don't want to do it from admin panel? In Joomla different templates can be assigned to any part of the site, and to auth/non-auth situations as well. Even in the older 1.5 series (and you didn't specify wich Joomla version you're referring to)

Comment: put that as an answer, and accept it, so that anyone who stumbles upon this will spot the solution, otherwise we're all left in the dark about what you wanted to do and what you did to make it work.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes ! this is a good question and a good answer, plus, it would be very helpful if someone wants to dynamically be able to choose different templates to display. You get +1 from me for both the question and the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem with assigning template manually through coding part.

I did by changing the function in includes/application.php

Function name is `getTemplate();` This function returns the template name.

Its worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried googling the subject?

Using "Joomla Pluggin User Template" i get a post regarding a pluggin provided by rockettheme that gives a dropdown list savable...

Maybe try to search next time?

http://www.google.ca/search?q=joomla+pluggin+template+per+user&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score -2):

i don't think so that it is possible, cause `Joomla` is a `CMS(Content Management System)`
and it has its own rule to develop your site.

If you want that kind of feature then you have to leave to use `CMS` and have to develop dynamic website

**EDIT** according to @jprofitt, it is possible with some `CSS` tricks, just detect the login session of the user and apply that `CSS` but i think, for this you have to detect the session on the `index.php` file, that is your template file, i am not sure cause i never did that.

Comment: Joomla has a templating system -- there's no reason it can't be extended to include this functionality.

Comment: @jprofitt you are right the functionality you will extend as much you can, the poster want to change the complete template.. AAh ofcause yes it is possible by Core CSS and a bit part of coding ;)

Comment: Joomla being a CMS doesn't mean you can't modify/extend its functionalities. And, btw, a CMS is a dynamic website. Your answer sounds just like a rant against CMSs...

Comment: I didn't say anything about CSS tricks. What I mean is that you could modify the templating system to see who the logged in user is, perform some lookup, and load the appropriate template. No trickery involved, just normal coding.

Comment: @jogesh_p a template is not just a modified set of CSS rules, but is a full html page with module placeholders and so on, you might need to change that as well. "Some CSS tricks" is not a solution, whatever it means

Comment: you can do this both through the administration and also through CSS/index.php customization.  Both ways are fairly straight forward, well documented and pretty easy.